# Multiple databases from an asynchronous config service?

Tags: nestjs

NestJS documentation describes how to define multiple databases:

https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#multiple-databases

As well as using a database config service for asynchronous configuration:

https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#async-configuration

Is it possible to define multiple databases from an async config service?

Experimentally I tried returning an array of options from my service:

```
class TypeOrmConfigService implements TypeOrmOptionsFactory {
  createTypeOrmOptions() {
    return [
      { ... },
      { ... }
    ];
  }
}
```

but no luck with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like for each connection you want to have you will need to create a separate configuration instance. What I might suggest would be some sort of factory that takes in a name, and maybe the config key for the database connection, then using those in the factory to help return the expected values. So the docs have a factory like

```js
TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
    type: 'mysql',
    host: configService.getString('HOST'),
    port: configService.getString('PORT'),
    username: configService.getString('USERNAME'),
    password: configService.getString('PASSWORD'),
    database: configService.getString('DATABASE'),
    entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
    synchronize: true,
  }),
  inject: [ConfigService],
});
```

You could create a similar factory along the lines of

```js
const typeOrmFactory = (
  configName: string,
  entities: string[],
  databaseName?: string
) => (configService: ConfigService): TypeOrmModuleOptions => ({
  type: 'postgres', // whatever you use
  url: configService.get(configName), // dynamically change which connection you're working with based on the factory input
  name: databaseName || 'default',
  synchronize: true,
  entities // path to the entity/entities you are working with
});
```

Now in your `app.module` you can use the factory like so

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: typeOrmFactory('DATABASE_URL', ['some/path.ts']),
      inject: [ConfigService]
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: typeOrmFactory('DATABASE_URL_2', ['some/other/path.ts'], 'secondaryDatabase'),
      inject: [ConfigServce]
    ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Make sure you tell Typescript that you are returning the type `TypeOrmModuleOptions` otherwise it tells you that the functions are not compatible. You can also save most of the configs in the config service and environment variables if you would like.